# How to set C++ standard in gcc compiler on Ubuntu VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running VS Code on freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Whatever I try, my language standard is stuck at c++17. I use gcc compiler.
To check the issue I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output is always the same: C++17

1. I've set `"cppStandard": "c++23",` in c_cpp_proporties.json.
2. I've set C++ standard in C/C++ Configurations settings to c++23.
3. I've set compiler arguments to `-std=c++23`.

I've been resetting VS Code, creating new files, reinstalling extensions, nothing.
Snippet from my tasks.json:

```
{
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Installed extensions:

- C/C++ by Microsoft
- C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft
- C/C++ Themes by Microsoft
- CMake Tools by Microsoft
- Better C++ Syntax by Jeff Hykin

Comment: ***I've set "cppStandard": "c++23", in c_cpp_proporties.json.*** Does your compiler support `c++23` ? Did you check the terminal to see the exact build command that was executed?

Comment: Adding `-std=c++23` in tasks.json is what affects the compilation. The rest only affects hints in the IDE.

Comment: The file `c_cpp_proporties.json` is for the editors IntelliSense, it's not use for building. Only `tasks.json` is used for building. And in `tasks.json` you must explicitly add the flags and options to the `args` list.

Comment: ***I've set compiler arguments to -std=c++23.*** Where did you do that?

Comment: I've been setting compiler argument in C/C++ Configurations in "Compiler arguments" window. Once I've moved it into `tasks.json` it started working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many of the commentators pointed out, `tasks.json` is used for compiling. @Some programmer dude correctly explained that I should put argument inside it. Updating `task.json` with the following code is the solution:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++23",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```